# microsoft robotics: cheap but very extensible robot?

Tags: robotics, programmer, kits, microsoft

Is there any cheap and very extensible robot kit, which can work with Microsoft Robotics?

I want to have a great choice of cool parts for a robot to buy :)

---

If where is no such robot kit which can work with MS Robotics, is there any chance to buy a very extensible robot which just can be programmed, maybe even in assembler?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A little basic research on your part would have turned up the Wikipedia entry for [Microsoft Robotics Developer Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft%5FRobotics%5FDeveloper%5FStudio), which lists no fewer than 16 robotics platforms that are compatible (to lesser or greater degree) with MRDS.  A little more browsing would have turned up Microsoft's list of [Supported Robots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb905437.aspx).

Frankly, if you want cheap, then using a Microsoft tool may look like the solution, but it will end up costing you more in the long run, because you'll be paying the [Microsoft tax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism%5Fof%5FMicrosoft), but that's your choice.  Every one of the 'supported robots' has a primary way of being programmed -- Microsoft is merely providing an alternative set of tools, in a desperate bid to capture more users of its OS, software, and tools.

Comment: I have Microsoft tool for free because of Dreamspark program :)

Comment: Wherein you prove my point :(

Comment: If you limit yourself to Microsoft Robotics then you are restricted in the platform you can use it with, as it looks like it is tied to the .net languages. if you learn some form of Basic, C or even Assembler then with a few minor alterations you can use them on different platforms with relatively little difficulty.

Comment: Agreeing with Amos - Don't tie yourself down to .net; you need to learn C.

Answer (score 2):

We built this autonomous robot with an Arduino.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6J_eh1HPu54

Granted its a hobby robot, but you can get more advanced.